# Embedded single tweet style

Tags: twitter, wordpress-theming, embed, tweets

What I want to do is to have the author copy/paste a twitter tweet link like so:

```
https://twitter.com/Reuters/status/811635259162791936
```

And then have my theme embed the tweet status content and link it to the original tweet instead of the twitter widget auto-embedded by wordpress.

But I can't seem to find a way to have my theme override or prevent the auto-embed from wordpress.

I also tried using css to style the embedded object so that it looked the way I wanted it to. It gets initially styled as expected and then after about half a second my styled tweet text gets replaced by the default twitter widget.

Comment: What I would do is make a custom field for the tweet. This way you are able to strip any possible formatting on WordPress' end, and do your own embedding and such as needed on your own end.

Comment: I may have not been precise enough in my question. The idea is to have it done automatically by modifying the output produced by wp.